"Could not open a connection to your authentication agent" error with running SSH Agent service
I have the following user service unit file set up to ensure that I have Github access at all times:
[Unit]
Description=SSH key agent

[Service]
Type=exec
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/ssh-agent.socket
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/ssh-add $GITHUBSSH

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target

If I run systemctl --user status ssh-agent.service, I see the following:
● ssh-agent.service - SSH key agent
     Loaded: loaded (/home/myUser/.config/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-10-25 20:10:27 EDT; 18h ago
 Invocation: 0b625b5fa3ed4386ab696da6979876ac
   Main PID: 2044 (ssh-agent)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 16673)
     Memory: 1.7M (peak: 3.2M)
        CPU: 31ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1001.slice/user@1001.service/app.slice/ssh-agent.service
             └─2044 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1001/ssh-agent.socket

Oct 25 20:10:27 fitzgeraldManjaro systemd[2010]: Starting SSH key agent...
Oct 25 20:10:27 fitzgeraldManjaro ssh-agent[2044]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1001/ssh-agent.socket; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
Oct 25 20:10:27 fitzgeraldManjaro ssh-agent[2044]: echo Agent pid 2044;
Oct 25 20:10:27 fitzgeraldManjaro ssh-add[2047]: Identity added: /home/myUser/.ssh/fitzgeraldManjaroGithub (myemail@address.com>
Oct 25 20:10:27 fitzgeraldManjaro systemd[2010]: Started SSH key agent.

ps -aux | grep 'ssh' confirms that PID 2044 is running and is indeed the ssh-agent command.
However, if I run ssh-add -l, I get the Could not open a connection to your authentication agent error. If I check on my other machine where I have this seem user service set up, I get the same status response and ssh-add -l returns the expected result: the key that I have told it to autoload. This service has worked every time with the above configuration without ever needing a call to eval "$(ssh-agent -s)".
If I run id on the machine where this is failing, my current user has uid=1001, which matches up with the CGroup line of the status message.
If I start a different ssh-agent process with eval "$(ssh-agent -s)", I can then add the key manually (though this of course defeats the purpose of the service); oddly, if I kill this ssh-agent process, though, I start getting a different error message when I run ssh-add -l which reads Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory.

GENERAL SSH SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com

For SSH agent to work, you must have SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable set and pointing to the SSH agent socket. AFAIK, ssh-agent -k relies on SSH_AGENT_PID containing the PID of the agent to work correctly.
The ssh-agent.service doesn't correctly export the ENV, so you should add it to your ~/.profile, possibly with a check that the socket actually exists (if [ -S "/run/user/$UID/ssh-agent.socket" ]; then ...), but that might cause an issue of its own.
